# Why i cannot run a php command inside bash file (OS Windows 10)?

Tags: php, windows, bash

i am new to bash and php commands. I would like to run a bash shell with some credentials and upload them into a server, through php command.
The code that i follow is attached below:

```
#!/bin/bash
name_user="Name"
firm="Firm"
php info.php;
```

the error message is :

> C:\xampp\htdocs\php_Code>bash run_php.sh
> run_php.sh: line 4: php: command not found

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried it running with the full path, but the problem remains.
Also, i have installed the bash for windows 10.

Comment: "I have tried it running with the full path, but the problem remains." - It should find the command if the path is right. Are you sure you've provided the correct path, in the format expected by bash?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes PHP is placed in non standard location so it's probably better first locate it and then try to execute.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
PHP=`which php`
$PHP info.php
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and your reply! Problem solved, php was not installed on bash.

Comment: `which` looks for commands in `PATH`. If the command was there, the problem wouldn't exist in the first place.

Comment: @BabisV. Bash is a shell, you don't install commands in bash. I presume you refer to the undisclosed Unix environment for Windows that you are using.